# How to get the second argument till the last one in csh?

Tags: linux, shell, alias, csh, review-board

I want to make an *alias* for the `rbt` command. I thought it should be:

```
alias myrbt 'rbt \!:1 --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl \!:2- \!:$'
```

the expected result is when I run

```
myrbt diff 12345
```

it should run

```
rbt diff --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl 12345
```

when I run

```
myrbt post 1.py 2.py
```

it should run

```
rbt post --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl 1.py 2.py
```

...but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which's the error message?

Comment: Please include the desired syntax for `myrbt`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
# Replace `echo` with `rbt`
$ alias myrbt 'echo \!:1 --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl \!:2*'

$ myrbt diff 12345
post --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl 12345

$ myrbt post 1.py 2.py
post --server=myserver --repository-url=myurl 1.py 2.py
```

The reason your version doesn't work is that with `\!:2-` doesn't seem to work if there are only two parameters (there need to be at least three).